# Github Public key permission denied

Tags: github

Gitbush is work fine but after my windows reinstall this is not any operation with github . When i pull or push something it make an error :

Permission denied (publickey). fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

How can i solve this ??

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the url used:

```
cd c:\path\to\your\repo
git remote -v
```

If it is ssh, you would need to [regenerate an ssh public/privbate key](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-an-ssh-key/), and register it to your GitHub repo.

Comment: first remove then regenerate by this way??  @VonC

Comment: No need to remove. But first, what is your url?

Comment: my url : c:\wamp\www\hospital

Comment: Do you mean git remote -v returns a local path? Not an https or an ssh url?

Comment: @NazmulHossain so it is https: you should enter your username/password. If git does not ask for them, it means they are cached. Are you on Windows? If you are, check your credential store: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39285119/6309

Comment: @NazmulHossain then check if you see an helper in git config -l. And check your Credential Store as illustrated in http://stackoverflow.com/a/39285119/6309